# Create new csv based on content of row

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a .csv called cleaned_data.csv formatted like so:

```
Date,State,Median Listing Price
1/31/2010,Alabama,169900
2/28/2010,Alabama,169900
3/31/2010,Alabama,169500
1/31/2010,Alaska,239900
2/28/2010,Alaska,241250
3/31/2010,Alaska,248000
```

I would like to create a new .csv file for each state, named {state}.csv, that has the Date and Median Listing Price.

So far I have this:

```
import pandas

csv = pandas.read_csv('cleaned_data.csv', sep='\s*,\s*', header=0, encoding='utf-8-sig')

state_list = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', ...]

for state in state_list:
    csv = csv[csv['State'] == f'{state}']
    csv.to_csv(f'state_csvs/{state}.csv', index=False, sep=',')
```

This successfully creates 51 .csv files named after each state, but only the Alabama.csv has Date, State, and Median Listing Price data for Alabama. Every other .csv only has the following headers with no data:

```
Date,State,Median Listing Price
```

Can someone explain to me why this is happening and how to fix it or a better way to do it?

Bonus points: I don't actually need the "State" column in the new .csv files but I'm unsure how to only add Date and Median Listing Price.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for i in df['State'].unique():
   df.loc[df['State'] == i][['Date', 'Median Listing Price']].to_csv(f'state_csvs/{i}.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: I am getting this error when trying to use that code:
  File "{filepath}", line 8, in <module>
    for i in df['State'].unique():
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

Comment: how is that possible when the word `filepath` is not even in my code

Comment: {filepath} is a placeholder for the file path of my python script file. The error is "for i in df['State'].unique(): TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable" and the file path isn't relevant.